# Scrolling background in overflowed div

Tags: css, background, overflow

I have a problem with scrolling content and background in overflowed div.

My case:

```
<style>
   .parent{
      background-image: url(http://www.google.lv/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
      width:100px;
      height:200px;
      overflow:scroll;
   }
   .parent div{
       background-color:red;
       width:10px;
       height:1000px;
   }
</style>
<div class="parent">
   <div>
      a
      b
      c
      f
      d
   </div>
</div>
```

The content is scrolling, but background of parent remains fixed. I want to scroll background also. I think it is possible without adding additional layer with desired background inside parent div.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Well, 2 years ago this might not have been the case, but `background-attachment:local;` solves the problem in Chrome 4+, IE 9+, Firefox 25+ and Safari 5+.

Support in mobile browsers is variable. Works in IOS, does not work in Android browser, and Android Chrome 47 claims to support it, but it doesn't work correctly in all cases yet.

I Updated @Alexey Ivanov's fiddle and removed the extra bg wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/nilloc/c5yfn81s/

Answer (score 1):

Set your background to the inner div, not to the container, because container stays on the same place, but your inner div is moving up.

```
<style>
   .parent{
      width:100px;
      height:200px;
      overflow:scroll;
   }
   .parent div{
       background-image: url(http://www.google.lv/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
       width:10px;
       height:1000px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Can't do that, because my inner div may have it's own background. And I don't want to add additional layer inside

Comment: Like an option you can move your background using JavaScript, but it's not good solution. You can do this via subscribing on `onscroll` event of your container and move background position on your `scrollOffset` value.

Comment: Also, you have only different background color inside of you content, so you can mix it with image: `background: #f00  url(http://www.google.lv/images/srpr/logo3w.png) no-repeat left top;`

Comment: Not the best way to mix backgrounds. For every element it is not needed, but having something with :first-child is not the best way, I think. It adds to the code unneeded complexity.

Comment: background-attachment:local; solves the problem, see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25329289/166279

Answer (score 0):

Don't know pure-css way to fix it (because overflow container sizes computed not from it's content size, but from the set size). Only way I can think of is by adding second container:

http://jsfiddle.net/cBMNs/1/

Comment: I did it, using the second container, but in order not to spoil my structure inside my .parent container, I just wrapped everything with div with overflow. The same, as you. But, still I think, it is possible with css, cause it is quite strange - why background on body scrolls, but in overflowed div not.